# How to bypass a 403 error after being blocked?

Tags: http-status-code-403

I am working on some php files on a shared hosting. I am constantly making changes to the files and then running them in a browser to see the changes.

After a few hours of work, I repeatedly start getting 403 errors and have to wait a few hours to "get back in".

I can open the files in a browser on my mobile phone on the same wifi connection, so it's the same IP, but I cannot open them in a different browser on my computer.

I am assuming the hosting company is blocking me because of the frequent loads. Some of the files I am working on also send out emails via PHPmailer and soon after I start getting the 403 errors, if I continue loading the pages in my mobile browser, PHPmailer stops working. Probably the hosting company blocking me again. Changing to my mobile browser doesn't help with the PHPmailer error.

What I am wondering is if there is some way to bypass the 403 error without using a different device. The PHPmailer error doesn't bother me as much, but a solution to that would also be helpful.

Additional information that may be useful... or not:
I use .htaccess to prevent all IPs except mine from accessing the files.
I tried deleting cookies and changing the DNS.
Tried ipconfig /flushdns and ipconfig/all
Have no idea if those experiments were good ideas or not though... :/

Comment: seems I am asking the wrong question. Typically, this would not be a problem the day after, but now it was still a problem 3 days later.
It seems that if I remove the "deny from all" and "allow from [ip]" from the htaccess and then everything works fine. But I cant keep it like that and I am not sure why this is happening...

Comment: Turns out my laptop was using IPv6 instead of IPv4. So allowing the IPv4 (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) instead of the longer IPv6 was not helping. Guess I had changed some settings...